# How to fix window configuration?

Tags: window-configuration

I use spacemacs and sometimes I need to fix window configuration 4 windows. Could somebody help with it?

I want to create 4 windows (split vertically and then both split horizontally)Then call some command like toggle-window-configuration-frozen and after that, I'd like to keep that configuration until- toggle back- C-x 0

At the moment, I experienced that, for example,

- *go test* buffer kills after keyboard-quit (C-g)
- window configuration resets on keyboard-escape-quit (C-u)

Comment: What does "fix window configuration 4 windows" means?  Solution to one possible interpretation is after window setup to use 'M-x window-configuration-to-register' aka 'C-x r w' to store and 'M-x jump-to-register' aka 'C-x r j' to restore.  But I may misinterpret the question.

Comment: found the answer here https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/fpx1zp/how_to_fix_window_configuration/flnppwv?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x